# stubbing init in ocmock3

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, stub, ocmock

creating init stubs was allowed in ocmock2 but is not allowed in ocmock3 ([9.3](http://ocmock.org/reference/#advanced-topics))

Is there anyway to get around this restriction? We were earlier on ocmock2 and would like to update but a lot of our test cases rely on init method stubs.

Answer (score 0):

Will be possible again in the next version (either 3.4.2 or 3.5): https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/pull/351